# how to save and upload an image in zf2 after renameing it and display it on the viewpage with working filters.?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want to upload an image in zf2 with the use of HTTP adapter and then rename it while saving to database and display it accordingly in view page. please help me out regarding this

Here is my form:

```
<?php
namespace Employee\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;

class EmployeeForm extends Form{
public function __construct($name=null){
parent::__construct($name);
$this->setAttribute('enctype','multipart/form-data');

    //$this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'imageupload',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'file',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Image Upload',
        ),
    ));

 $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'submit',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'submit',
            'value' => 'Add',
            'id' => 'submitbutton',
        ),
    ));

   }
}
```

here is my view file:

```
 <?php $form->prepare(); ?>
 <?php echo $this->form()->openTag($form); ?>

 <?php  echo $this->formRow($form->get('imageupload')); ?>       
 <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('submit')); ?>
 <?php echo $this->form()->closeTag(); ?>
```

here is the code in controller action:

```
if($request->isPost()){

    $files =  $request->getFiles()->toArray();
    $httpadapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
     $httpadapter->setDestination('public/images/profile');
   $httpadapter->receive($files['file']['name']);
```

Now I want to save only image name in database with newname(rename) and view image with certain validation of that image like size and type. thank you

Comment: Please start with looking at the Zend Framework documentation or at tutorials regarding this matter. I'm sure you can find many helpful articles.

Comment: i asked here, after i go through the documentation of zf2 as well many other sites but none helps

Comment: You have to at least show some code that you tried, what steps have you done to achieve your goal, be more specific and show your work.

Comment: you need attach inputfiler with your form for size and type. when you get post data you need to call form->isValid() to validate your image and other stuff. and really you need to do lot of study first